# Running Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand through Azure automation

Tags: powershell, azure-automation

I am trying to run a script thorugh Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand from azure automation but it is showing cmdlet does not exist. Please let me know how to implement this.

### Below the script

```
Invoke-AzureRMVMRunCommand -ResourceGroup 'XXXXXX' -Name XXXXX-CommandID 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath 'Test.ps1'
```

### Error details.

```
Invoke-AzureRMVMRunCommand : The term 'Invoke-AzureRMVMRunCommand' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, 
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is 
correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-AzureRMVMRunCommand -ResourceGroup 'olf3em-rds-mgmt' -Name OLF   ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Invoke-AzureRMVMRunCommand:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Hi, I am running from azure automation, I don't think there is any way to install module.

Comment: Just learnt that the -ScriptPath denotes the local VM where the script resides. How were you able to run this in Azure automation? Do you first have to copy the script from a storage account and then run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install modules before using those:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-runbook-gallery#modules-in-powershell-gallery

in short:

go to modules
browse gallery
install

Comment: I am getting another error, could you please check. Test.ps1 is another Runbook.



Invoke-AzureRMVMRunCommand : Could not find file 'C:\Temp\nkfpflse.yba\Test1.ps1'.
At line:27 char:1
+ Invoke-AzureRMVMRunCommand -ResourceGroup $vm.ResourceGroupName -Name ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.Automation.InvokeAzureRmVMRunCommand

Comment: create a new question please (as this is a separate issue)

Answer (score 0):

The Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand command is included in the AzureRM.Compute module. Which you will first need to install in your Automation Account.